# The image of a dual transformation is equal to the set of annihilators of the kernel of the original transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, duality-theorems

I'm presented with the following question:

> Suppose $T:V \to W$ is a linear map and $V$ is finite dimensional. Prove Im $T'$ = (Ker $T$)$^0$.

I have showed that Im $T'$ $\subseteq$ (Ker $T$)$^0$:

Let $f \in$Im $T'$. Then for $v \in $ Ker $T$.

$$\begin{align}
f(v) &= T'(g)(v) \text{ for some } g\in W'\\
&=g(T(v))\\
&=g(0)\\
&=0\end{align}$$
and so $f\in$(Ker $T$)$^0$ $\Rightarrow$ Im $T'$ $\subseteq$ (Ker $T$)$^0$

But when it comes to showing Im $T'$ $\supseteq$ (Ker $T$)$^0$, I am not sure how to proceed. I'm quite sure I need to use the finite dimensionality of $V$ somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1344904/show-that-ker-hatt-textann-textrange-t) is related (but not quite a duplicate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do things is by counting dimensions.

In particular, let $r$ be the dimension of the image of $T$, and let $n$ be the dimension of $V$.  By the rank-nullity theorem, $\ker T$ has dimension $n - r$.  Then, we note that $(\ker T)^0$ must have dimension $r$ (you may have to prove this yourself).

On the other hand, note that $T'$ has the same rank as $T$, which means that $\operatorname{Im}T'$ is $r$-dimensional.

Now, by your work, $\operatorname{Im}T'$ is an $r$-dimensional subspace of $(\ker T)^0$, which is also $r$-dimensional.  It follows that $\operatorname{Im}T' = (\ker T)^0$, which was the desired conclusion.

Comment: I had a look at your answer on the other problem, and that was the kind of thing I was gunning for, but I like this more from a learning perspective, since you've used a different area of linear algebra. Thanks very much!

Comment: No problem.  Interestingly, I think the proof I gave on the other question works for infinite-dimensional spaces as well, but I believe that your statement is no longer true in that context.

Comment: Hi! Sorry but why rank of $T$ and $T'$ are the same?

Comment: @ZFR this is a standard result. One way to prove it is to use the existence of a “rank factorization”.